# Msg 4845, Level 16, State1 Bulk copy failed. Client does not have the capability to bulk copy into the data-only locked table

Tags: sybase

I am trying to insert data from file to sybase table but while using bcp_init I get this error

Bulk copy or insertion. When I am trying to insert an empty file with bcp on terminal it works. But fails via code using bcp_init